# Convert characters in total duration to numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data like this in Excel:

```
Duration:
PT7M37S
PT9M30S
PT2M16S
PT4M22S
PT31S
PT15S
PT3M20S
PT58S
PT27M50S
```

But, I want to convert it to 457 (7*60+37) seconds. Is there any easy way to do this, because I have 22,000 samples like this?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or a VBA code?

Comment: @RacilHilan formula would be good, if possible. Otherwise, please provide VBA code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Excel formula that construct the formula that you want:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"PT","="),"M","*60" & IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="S","+","")),"S","")
```

This will give you the text `=7*60+37`, but the problem now is how to execute it as a formula. Sadly, I don't know of any way to execute a text as formula except using the `EVALUATE()` function which is only available in VBA. You can add a module and paste this function in it:

```
Function Eval(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(value)
End Function
```

Now, you can use it to execute your formula:

```
=Eval(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"PT",""),"M","*60" & IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="S","+","")),"S",""))
```

Alternatively, you can do the entire calculation in VBA:

```
Function CalcSeconds(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    value = Replace(value, "PT", "")
    value = Replace(value, "M", "*60" + IIf(Right(value, 1) = "S", "+", ""))
    CalcSeconds = Evaluate(Replace(value, "S", ""))
End Function
```

And now your formula will simply be:

```
=CalcSeconds(A1)
```

**EDIT** To add the hours calculation:

```
Function CalcSeconds(ByVal value As String) As Long
    Dim ending As String
    ending = Right(value, 1)
    value = Replace(value, "PT", "")
    value = Replace(value, "H", "*3600" + IIf(ending = "M" Or ending = "S", "+", ""))
    value = Replace(value, "M", "*60" + IIf(ending = "S", "+", ""))
    CalcSeconds = Evaluate(Replace(value, "S", ""))
End Function
```

Comment: =Calcseconds function works, but can you also suggest me a code to convert the samples with Hours data. Like PT1H10M48S
PT12M22S
PT1H42M31S

Comment: See the edit in my updated answer.

Comment: Great. But, if the H values are greater than or equal to 10, the calculated sample is showing "#VALUE"

Comment: It's just overflowing the `Integer`. Change the return type to `Long` and it will work. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had an incompletely thought out solution similar to Scott's. I see he has posted a good formula solution.

Here is a UDF, that will also work.  It uses regular expressions to find the appropriate minutes and seconds, and then combines them.

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtrSec(S As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sM As String = "\d+(?=M)"
    Const sS As String = "\d+(?=S)"
    Dim L As Long
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = sM
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        L = MC(0) * 60
    End If

    .Pattern = sS
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        L = L + MC(0)
    End If
End With

ExtrSec = L

End Function
```

Regular Expressions are probably overkill for this, and you can accomplish what you request with all native VBA functions:

```
Function ExtrSec2(ByVal value As String) As Variant
    Dim M As Long, S As Long
    Dim locM As Long, locS As Long

value = Mid(value, 3)
    locM = InStr(value, "M")
    locS = InStr(value, "S")

'We do not check specifically for the presence of PT
'  at the beginning, but we could, if necessary
If locM + locS = 0 Then
    ExtrSec2 = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

If locM > 0 Then
    M = Val(value) * 60
    value = Mid(value, locM + 1)
End If

    S = Val(value)

ExtrSec2 = M + S
End Function
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for critique

Comment: Ron, Feel free to take the formula back, I was about to post it as comment when you deleted the answer.  It is your answer, I just polished it a little.

Comment: @ScottCraner No need. Your polish is what was required.

Comment: Not fan of your first function, so will only comment on the second one. 1) You don't need `locS`, you're not even using it. 2) You don't need `S = Val(value)` inside `If`, the one outside is enough for all cases. Otherwise, a good simple calculation.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks for your comments. With regard to the *inside S=*, good catch. With regard `locS`, I was going to add a check to ensure that we had at least one M or S, but was interrupted and didn't. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

This creates and time string and multiplying it by the number of seconds in a day.  `PT` becomes `00:`, `M` becomes `:` and we remove the `S`.  The end result is something like `00:07:37` which Excel can resolve to an actual time

When `M` is not found we put `0M` in the string prior to making the replacements to ensure we put seconds where they belong:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("M",A1)),A1,REPLACE(A1,3,0,"0M")),"PT","00:"),"M",":"),"S","")*86400
```

[image]

Comment: It's a nice solution :) Props to Ron too

Comment: All props go to RonRosenfeld.  I was going down a totally different track.  I just helped overcome the no minutes issue.  I made it a community wiki, as it is more Ron's than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample is in cell A1:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))-FIND("M",A1))*60+LEFT((RIGHT(A1,FIND("M",A1)-1)), LEN((RIGHT(A1,FIND("M",A1)-1)))-1)
```

Comment: I get errors when no Minutes and when the minutes is more than 1 character.